# How to read XML returned by HTTP POST request?

Tags: java, xml, http, post, httpurlconnection

**NOT a duplicate of my other question.**

I am sending a `POST` request like this:

```
        String urlParameters = "a=b&c=d";
        String request = "http://www.example.com/";

        URL url = new URL(request);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();      
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        connection.disconnect();
```

How can I read the xml response returned from a HTTP `POST` request? Particularly, I want to save the response file as a .xml file, and then read it. For my usual `GET` requests, I use this:

```
    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
    URL website = new URL(urlToParse);
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("request.xml");
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
    fos.close();
    // Do the work
```

**Addendum**: I'm using the following code and it works just fine. However, it neglects any spacing and new lines and treats the complete XML contents as a single line. How do I fix it?

```
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb1.append(line);
    }
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("request.xml");
    f.write(sb1.toString().getBytes());
    f.close();
    br.close();
```

Comment: Try getting an inputstream from the connection and reading from it, right after you finish writing to your outputstream?

Comment: @bdares Please see OP for my edit.

Answer (score 1):

don't use `Readers` and `readLine()` with xml data.  use `InputStreams` and `byte[]`s.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Pangea, I modified his code and this now works:

```
    TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer t= transFactory.newTransformer();
    t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT,"yes");                
    Source input = new StreamSource(is);
    Result output = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("request.xml"));
    transFactory.newTransformer().transform(input, output);
```